# INFORMATICA free version of data loader : Does it support bi-directional sync?

Tags: integration, data-loader, informatica

Using a Corporate Enterprise Licence, I don't have access to BULK or SOAP API but only to REST.

It seems that the best way to do cost effective interfaces to external tables / files would be to use INFORMATICA free version of data loader.

But :
- does it support bi-directional sync ?
- does a bi-directional flow count for one end point or two end points (the free version is limited to two end points).

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I believe it would count as TWO endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I believe the free version allows for one cloud endpoint and one database/flat file. I agree with Eric's comment above. I think it would count as two endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different data synch tasks
Task1 - endpoint 1 as source and endpoint 2 as target
Task2 - endpoint 2 as source and endpoint 1 as target

add both of them to a task flow(not sure if task flow available in free version) run/schedule the task flow so that both task runs in sequential order.  You can also trigger the task flow using REST.